# How to write unit test for switch case in jasmine and coffee

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, jasmine

I am newbie in `jasmine` and `coffee`.

My question looks familiar to others, but it is not.

Please take a look of my snippet

**Coffee Code**

```
$scope.changeText = ->
  $timeout $scope.changeText, 5000
  id = parseInt(Math.random() * 4)
  switch id
    when 0
      $scope.home.banner.mainHead =  'Some Heading'
      $scope.home.banner.subHead =  'Some more text'
    when 1
      $scope.home.banner.mainHead =  'Some other Heading'
      $scope.home.banner.subHead =  'Some more text'
    when 2
      $scope.home.banner.mainHead =  'Another Heading'
      $scope.home.banner.subHead =  'Another Text'
    when 3
      $scope.home.banner.mainHead =  'Another Heading 1'
      $scope.home.banner.subHead =  'Text text text'

  return
$timeout($scope.changeText, 5000)
```

How to Start write test case in jasmine?

THanks in Advance.

Comment: What exactly do you want to test? What is the expected behavior of your code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your snippet is that it generates a random `id`, hence it cannot be tested deterministically. However, what you could test is whether `mainHead` and `subHead` are changed accordingly with regards to `id`. Therefore I would split that snippet into a testable function with the `switch` statement and the rest:

COFFEE:

```
getBanner = (id) -> 
    banner = {}

    switch id
        when 0
            banner.mainHead = "Some Heading"
            banner.subHead  = "Some more text"
        when 1
            banner.mainHead = "Some other Heading"
            banner.subHead  = "Some more text"
        when 2
            banner.mainHead = "Another Heading"
            banner.subHead  = "Another text"
        when 3
            banner.mainHead = "Another Heading 1"
            banner.subHead  = "Text text text"

    banner

$scope.changeText = ->
    id = parseInt(Math.random() * 4)
    $scope.home.banner = getBanner(id)

# $interval might be better in your use case than $timeout
$interval $scope.changeText, 5000
```

TESTS:

```
describe "getBanner", ->

    it "should return mainHead/subHead", ->
        banner = getBanner(0)
        expect(banner.mainHead).toEqual("Some Heading")
        expect(banner.subHead).toEqual("Some more text")

        banner = getBanner(1)
        # ...

    it "should return empty banner on wrong id", ->
        # testing edge cases
        banner = getBanner(-1)
        expect(Object.keys(banner).length).toEqual(0)
```